# fsolve gives an error when there is no solution + help me traceback the error messages

Tags: r, numerical-methods

I am new to R and would like to learn the basics of how R can solve equations numerically.

**My questions are:**

- fsolve returns an error when there are no solutions. Why? How can I get it to return nan or empty?
- (more general): please help me understand the traceback and error messages in R - they seem too cryptic to be of any use.

**Let me explain:**

I started with how to calculate the internal rate of return, not because there aren’t any functions to calculate it, but because it’s an easy example to start with.

As a reminder, given a set of cashflows at equal periods (eg all one year after another), the IRR is the interest rate `i` such that the sum of the formulas in the column “formulas” below is zero; of course `(1+i)^ 0 = 1`

```
╔════════╦═════════════╦════════════════╗
║ period ║   cashflow  ║     formulas   ║
╠════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╣
║      0 ║       -100  ║ -100 / (1+i)^0 ║
║      1 ║         10  ║  10 /  (1+i)^1 ║
║      2 ║        110  ║ 110 / (1+i)^2  ║
╚════════╩═════════════╩════════════════╝
```

I have put together the code at the bottom, and it works with both `uniroot` and `fsolve` in an easy case like (-100,10,110), where the solution is 10%.

However, **when there is no solution (e.g. all positive numbers), then uniroot returns empty, as it should, but fsolve gives me this error:**

> Error in if (norm(s, "F") < tol || norm(as.matrix(ynew), "F") < tol)
>   break :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I found this similar [question](https://stackanswers.net/questions/error-is-fsolve-in-r-when-trying-to-fill-a-matrix-with-values-looking-for-explanation-and-or-solution) , but no answer.
I haven’t found anything in the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/pracma.pdf).

**Why? What does it mean? How can I get fsolve to return empty or nan when there is no solution, without breaking the execution of the script?**

**EDIT**: In reply to the answer below:
 **Can you recommend another R package that, unlike uniroot, doesn't require you to specify upper and lower bounds in which to look for a solution?**

`pracma::fsolve` is only meant for the cases where `n >= 2`. Is this documented? I couldn't find it mentioned in the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/pracma.pdf).
The fsolve functions in [Python Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) and in [Matlab](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) do not, as far as I know, have this limitation, nor do they require you to specify upper and lower bounds. I do not have Matlab but Scipy doesn't give an error when there is no solution.
Also, I tried to find the root of `x^2+5` , and `pracma::fsolve` gave a warning because it didn't converge, but not an error.

**Related question: how can I get meaningful and useful traceback in R?**

Eg this happens in Python, where I get messages that tell me that line x in my code called line y in some_other_code which failed.

But in R? I have debug -> on error -> error inspector activated in Rstudio. If I type `traceback()` I get:

```
> traceback()
6: broyden(f, x0, J0 = J(x0), maxiter = maxiter, tol = tol)
5: fsolve(my_npv, x0 = 0.2, cf = cf) at solve_irr.R#20
4: eval(ei, envir)
3: eval(ei, envir)
2: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
1: source("H:/R/solve_irr.R")
```

which is not very useful because it’s not clear at all where the error is; yes, line 20 of solve_irr triggered it, but then what is “broyden”?

Where is it?

A function of which package (OK, here it must be part of pracma, but the debugger should tell me – in more complex settings understanding what is causing the error won’t be as straightforward)? In which line of the code is the error? Where is `if (norm( etc`? In broyden?

EDIT: code:

```
library(rootSolve)
library(pracma)

my_npv <- function(cf,i){
  npv <- 0
    for (t in 1:length(cf)){
      npv <- npv + cf[[t]] / (1+i)^(t-1)
    }
  return(npv)
}

# this works
cf <- c(-100,10,110)

#this doesn't:
cf <- c(100,10,110)

i_uniroot <- uniroot.all(my_npv, c(0,1), cf = cf)
i_fsolve <- fsolve(my_npv, x0 = 0.2, cf = cf)
```

Answer (score 2):

Function `fsolve` and especially the *Broyden* method is not appropriate for univariate root finding, it is only meant for the case f:R^n -> R^n with n >= 2. More precisely: The 'Sherman-Morrison formula' does not always work correctly in the 1-dim case. In the future, `fsolve` will stop working for univariate functions with a more speaking error message.

The standard root finder is `uniroot` in Base R. There are several other 1-dim root-finding functions available in R, some of them in the *pracma* package. Like `uniroot.all`, `findroots` will attempt to find all roots in a given interval.

This does not answer your question about debugging facilities in R. See for instance [Debugging with RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio) which contains a section on "Debugging in Packages". There are Youtube videos about debugging with R. Still I would recommend to send a bug report instead of debugging package code you haven't written yourself.

Comment: thank you! Are you the author of the package? I have added an edit to my original question, in reply to your answer. Do you mean this findRoots: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/drgee/versions/1.1.6/topics/findRoots ?

Comment: `fsolve` in R is *not* `fsolve` in MATLAB. If you have complaints about it, write to the package author, Stackoverflow will not be the appropriate place. For supplying a single starting value instead of an interval, Newton-Raphson could be right for you, there are several implementations in R packages, see '??newton'. Note that Newton-Raphson will have other disadvantages.

Comment: Well, the package documentation https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/pracma.pdf mentions the similarity with Matlab! May I ask again how you know about n>=2 and if it is documented anywhere? Clarifying this would be relevant for stackoverflow, I believe.

Comment: pracma::newtonRaphson works, but gives a warning when there is no solution. Is there a way to suppress the warning? Thanks